# Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child() firebase realtime database login

Tags: java, android, database, firebase

I am having an error performing queries on firebase. my query code is this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ref.child(userName) != null) {
                login();
            }else if(ref.child(userName) == null){
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "The username and password you entered did not match our records. Please double-check and try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Username Doesn't Exist",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void login(){
    a.setMessage("Logging in");
    a.show();
    userName = username.getText().toString();
    password = pw.getText().toString();
    ref.child(userName).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            UserProfiles userProfiles = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserProfiles.class);
            if(userName.equals(userProfiles.getUsername())){
             a.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Successful!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Home.class));
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Incorrect Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

This is the logcat of the error

> 2019-02-27 23:32:27.114 22677-22677/com.example.ils E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.ils, PID: 22677
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
>           at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:101)
>           at com.example.ils.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:48)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
>           at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
>           at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

what seems to be the problem of my code?

Comment: Are you sure your `userName` is not `null`?

Comment: Doesn't look like `userName` has been initialized when running `if (ref.child(userName) != null)`

Comment: @Tom I just want to show the toast if the user entered an empty username on the login. if I will initialize the username where would I put it?

Comment: You can check if `userName == null` and create a Toast for that. Then you'll when this will happen and then you can decide how to properly handle this situation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67449449/4828650